# Visual Studio 2012 setup crashes when trying to install

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

In my Win7(64 bit) PC, I installed VS 2012 Ultimate Trial version few days back and today i got my msdn subscription of VS2012 Premium. so i uninstalled the Trial and was trying to run the setup exe for VS 2012 and dit is crashing. this is the error details i am seeing. Anybody know how to fix this ?

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BEX   Application
>   Name: en_visual_studio_premium_2012_x86_web_installer_920759.exe
>   Application Version:  11.0.50727.1   Application Timestamp:   4fd9f28c
>   Fault Module Name:    igdumd32.dll   Fault Module Version:    8.15.10.2057
>   Fault Module Timestamp:   4b5e4895   Exception Offset:    00015216
>   Exception Code:   c0000409   Exception Data:  00000000   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48   Locale ID:  1033   Additional
>   Information 1:    1d75   Additional Information
>   2:    1d7537ede8bee0a1d08a5f0d2036cc52   Additional Information 3:    b4a4
>   Additional Information 4: b4a4e02d592ed99de97ca18a461b34ee
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be possible that some VS 2012 updates (it will show in sys tray) are available try installing update.
2. Try installing VS 2010 then VS 2012. VS 2012 has some dependency on VS 2010 components.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and it turned out to be a compatibility issue. Microsoft has a KB patch to apply to fix that issue.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2781514.